# Count all child for a GUID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I want a count of all child and sub child of where a particular parent exists.

I have this data:

```
 |                     Id                  | Parent 
 +-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+  
 |  736F8C6A-D58D-442E-BE2E-3B9F0595C58B   | NULL                                |
 |  CA828BBA-6657-46FC-BA26-7ED8C7FB220C   | 736F8C6A-D58D-442E-BE2E-3B9F0595C58B|
 |  2DB8A8F9-9F29-4F3A-907F-A6ACEDE12859   | 736F8C6A-D58D-442E-BE2E-3B9F0595C58B|
```

If I pass `736F8C6A-D58D-442E-BE2E-3B9F0595C58B`, then it should return the total count of its children and grandchildren - that is a total of 2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i used the following query to create the temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #TBLTEMP(ID int, ParentID int)

INSERT INTO #TBLTEMP(ID,ParentID)
VALUES(1,NULL)
,(2,1)
,(3,2)
,(4,2)
,(5,3)
,(6,NULL)
,(7,6)
,(8,NULL)
,(9,NULL)
```

Then i used the following query to retrieve childs count

```
WITH CTE_1(ParentID) AS(
    SELECT ParentID FROM #TBLTEMP T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T2.ParentID FROM CTE_1 c
    INNER JOIN #TBLTEMP T2 ON c.ParentID = T2.ID
    WHERE T2.ParentID > 0
), CTE_2 AS ( SELECT ID , 0 as cnt FROM #TBLTEMP T3 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_1 c2 where c2.ParentID = T3.ID))
SELECT ParentID, count(*) as cnt 
FROM CTE_1
WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ParentID
UNION
SELECT ID as ParentID, cnt FROM CTE_2

ORDER BY ParentID
```

The result is:

[image]

**Reference**

- [Recursive CTE to find Total for all children](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138928/recursive-cte-to-find-total-for-all-children)

## Update 1

To getcount for a specific ID:

```
WITH CTE_1(ParentID) AS(
    SELECT ParentID FROM #TBLTEMP T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T2.ParentID FROM CTE_1 c
    INNER JOIN #TBLTEMP T2 ON c.ParentID = T2.ID
    WHERE T2.ParentID > 0
), CTE_2 AS ( SELECT ID , 0 as cnt FROM #TBLTEMP T3 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_1 c2 where c2.ParentID = T3.ID)), CTE_3 AS(
SELECT ParentID, count(*) as cnt 
FROM CTE_1
WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ParentID
UNION
SELECT ID as ParentID, cnt FROM CTE_2) 
SELECT cnt FROM CTE_3 WHERE ParentID = 1
```

Comment: where do I pass the id and I just want a count of a particular not the count of all record

Comment: my actual contains GUID for both the column and it is giving me **uniqueidentifier is incompatible with tinyint** any help ? @hadi
I have added  **= '736F8C6A-D58D-442E-BE2E-3B9F0595C58B'** anywhere else i have to change

Comment: @abhi replace `WHERE T2.ParentID > 0` with `WHERE T2.ParentID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: yes, I tried it it's working fine. but I don't have much data. will check after some time and sure if it works then I mark it as an answer. currently stuck with some other problem of SQL query. which cannot explain on StackOverflow if you can connect with me that would be a great help [contact](https://singhabhimanyu.com)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187789/discussion-between-abhi-and-hadi).

Comment: @abhi you can ask for additional thing on the chat. But if the answer solved the issue explained in the question you have to accept or upvote the answer. You cannot wait until all your issues were solved.